# Visual Studio 2015 collapse/toggle XML comments only

Tags: xml, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, code-folding

I want to know if there is a way to collapse/toggle **only** XML function comments. If I choose **Collapse to Definitions** in Visual Studio 2015, that collapses all of my functions as well as the accompanying XML comments, I want a way to collapse/toggle only XML comments. Is this possible in visual studio 2015? If so how can I do it?

By XML comments I refer to this:

[image: XML Comment Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [NoComment](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=3dGrabber.NoComment) extension for Visual Studio seems to do exactly what you're looking for.

> This extension replaces comments with a callout icon.
>   Comments can be shown by hovering over the icon (Tooltip)

Comment: That's it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The [CollapseComments](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MattLaceyLtd.CollapseComments) extension does it.
Difference from the NoComment is that it does not replace the comments with icons. It still shows the first line of the summary line, like when you collapse the XML comment manually.